# Scoping authorization to current devise user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

My Rails 3.2 project has a devise-generated user and a set of models that all contain data that's specific to that user. I want a logged-in user to be able to access only his own data through the APIs exposed by the controllers.

Now, a brute-force way to enable this would be to change each and every controller from something like:

```
def index
  @stuff = Stuff.all
```

to

```
def index
  @stuff = Stuff.find_all_by_user_id current_user.id
```

And I have to repeat this for every single action of every single controller. Is there perhaps a more succinct and DRY way of achieving the same effect? The amount of boilerplate I have to write feels wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) gem.

Comment: I think this should do the trick, I'll let you folks know if it's not cutting it!

Answer (score 0):

a) You can have a **before callback in application_controller.rb** that looks something like

```
def find_stuff_from_current_user
  @stuff = Stuff.find_all_by_user_id current_user.id
end
```

And than call this in every controller like this:

```
before_filter :find_stuff_from_current_user
```

Now you have @stuff variable available in every controller and in every action.

b) Or **you can use scoping in stuff model.rb** where you say something like:

```
scope :stuff_from_current_user, where(:user => current_user)
```